# Reference variable in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function and inside that function I create variables. I want to use the created variable as a threshold for filtering.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION someF(a integer, b integer, c integer)
RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
    problematicVariable float := $1 / $2;

BEGIN
    FOR i in 1 .. $3:
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS someTable AS
        SELECT someFunction( 
            'SELECT id, 
            FROM yetAnotherTable st 
            WHERE st.agg <= problematicVariable')
    END LOOP;
END
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

However, I get the error that:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "problematicVariable" does not exist
> ```

How would I tell postgres that this is not a column but a variable I created within the function body?

Comment: `WHERE st.agg <= ' || problematicVariable)`

Comment: Referencing a variable is the least of your problems. Division by zero, integer division, `SELECT` instead of `SELECT *`, repeated `CREATE TABLE` with the same table name ... your approach is one big mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the *name* `problematicVariable` is interpreted in `someFunction()`, where it is obviously not defined. Since that is a stable call (the function parameter is always the same so the same data would return from the function on every call, assuming no dependency on volatile values) you are better off taking that out of the loop and calling `someF()` repeatedly with the result of that first function call.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION someF(a integer, b integer, c integer) RETURNS someType AS $$
DECLARE
    problematicVariable float := $1 / $2;
    idVar someType;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO idVar 
    FROM yetAnotherTable st 
    WHERE st.agg <= problematicVariable;

    FOR i IN 1 .. $3 LOOP
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS someTable AS
            SELECT someFunction(idVar);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Enlighten me. The logic in the code in the question makes no sense, the coding style is "loose" and there are several *potential* pathologies, but there are no bugs as such. Assuming `b != 0` and that the first select produces a single row, the code will run just fine. To me it just seems that the OP has quickly patched together some code that demonstrates the issues (s)he was faced with (functions named `someF()` and `someFunction()` don't look like real code to me) and I addressed that particular issue, with *actual* bugs removed.

Comment: I commented under the question.

Comment: @Patrick your write. I pateched together something, which of course, is not "real code". However, it serves to demonstrate what I was asking. Imho an abstract example of what I was going for was enough in this case, because it was rather a question of "structural understatement" than of problem that would occur with the function executing.

Comment: I completely agree with you and that is what I tried to tell Erwin. I actually thought your question was rather good (how to reference a parameter or a variable of a function in a sub-function?) so I gave you a +1 for it. Someone else - maybe Erwin, maybe someone else - downvoted it for reasons unknown to me.